# What's the easiest way to make an element shrink to smallest length that still fits n columns of child elements?

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

Consider the following example image:
[image: Left side column expands infinitely vs right side parent shrinks to fit]

Id like to have the following enforcements that can restrict the parent element:

1. The parent's width is implicitly wide enough to fit exactly 2 columns wide worth of children
2. The parent will automatically shrink it's height to "pack" as tightly the children elements. Children overflow from column 1 to column 2.

Mathematically this should be enough information to do by hand for any given sizes of children. The children's width will all be consistent, but their heights will be variable.

However there exists a mathematical minima that the parent container can shrink to before it cannot shrink anymore, as both columns will become saturated and attempting to shrink any further would cause children to start flowing past its height.

Is there any css trick to force this to happen, such that as I arbitrarily add children to the parent, it naturally evenly distributes them across the two columns?

Comment: No there is not. CSS can't do much *unless* the height is defined.

Comment: Although CSS `column-count` might offer some help here but I'm not sure if that is what you are after.